# JQuery is not working in django (Showing $ is not defined)

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my code. I have a static folder in which i have all css and js files

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>template is working</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'style.css' %}">
    <script href="{% static 'js/jquery.js' %}"></script>
    <script href="{% static 'js/bootstrap.js' %}"></script>
    <script>
        var jQuery = django.jQuery;
        var $ = jQuery;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert("Hello");
        })
    </script>
</head>
```

Here is the screenshot of directory structure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAy5O.png)

Comment: Can you share the actual error message?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to do but those line are not necessary:

```
 var jQuery = django.jQuery;
 var $ = jQuery;
```

Answer (score 0):

I, as @Stéphane also have no idea what are you trying to do, because as I know, jQuery `ready` statement defined like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

or...

```
// Shorthand for $( document ).ready()
$(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

Also, I think this question even don't related to Django framework. If you want use jQuery, you should read [its documentation](https://jquery.com/).